# phpword show file content in browser

Tags: php, phpword

I am using [PhpWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) package to edit my `docx` files contents, it is working just fine when I provide static replacement values in controller, but in order to have fully dynamic functionality of editing my files, I need to show `docx` content in my browser before actually replace the values and store final file.

**So my question is** how can I show/preview my file content before creating new version of it?

## Code

```
public function updateDocx(Request $request)
{
    $template_file_name = 'myFile.docx';

    $rand_no = rand(111111, 999999);
    $fileName = "results_" . $rand_no . ".docx";

    $folder   = "results_";
    $full_path = $folder . '/' . $fileName;

    try
    {
        if (!file_exists($folder))
        {
            mkdir($folder);
        }

        //Copy the Template file to the Result Directory
        copy($template_file_name, $full_path);

        // add calss Zip Archive
        $zip_val = new \ZipArchive;

        //Docx file is nothing but a zip file. Open this Zip File
        if($zip_val->open($full_path) == true)
        {
            // In the Open XML Wordprocessing format content is stored.
            // In the document.xml file located in the word directory.
            $key_file_name = 'word/document.xml';
            $message = $zip_val->getFromName($key_file_name);

            $timestamp = date('d-M-Y H:i:s');

            // this data Replace the placeholders with actual values
            $message = str_replace("[company_name]",  "ABC Co.", $message);

            //Replace the content with the new content created above.
            $zip_val->addFromString($key_file_name, $message);
            $zip_val->close();
        }
        return response()->download(public_path($full_path));
    }
    catch (Exception $exc)
    {
        $error_message =  "Error creating the Word Document";
        var_dump($exc);
    }
}
```

#### Explanation

This code above will automatically generate new file and replace provided strings, what I need is creating new function (make this function shorter) to just load and preview the content of my file instead of edit and create new file.

**Any idea?**

Comment: The only way I could make it happen so far, was to generate `PDF` version of my file and return that `PDF` as preview. Still happy to see if someone can make actually `.docx` preview.